# problem with including pdf using pdfpages

Tags: graphics, pdftex, pdf, pdfpages

I am trying to use `\includepdf` with about 20 different PDFs. The first 19 have worked fine, but the last one which can be found below

http://math.unc.edu/for-grad-students/analysiscompsSprJan2011.pdf

will not load properly. However, there are no errors - the PDF produced just has a blank page with a couple of black lines in the middle. I converted the PDF to JPG and used `\includegraphics` and it loaded properly but then I could not add it to my table of contents in the way I wanted.

Any thoughts on why it won't load as a `.pdf` but will as `.jpg`?

Here's a minimal document that shows the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf{analysiscompsSprJan2011.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: I've added a minimal document that shows the problem.

Comment: This is a bug in pdftex; please open a bug with the [bugtracker](http://sarovar.org/projects/pdftex/).

Answer (score 6):

It seems pdfTeX has trouble with the font encodings in `analysiscompsSprJan2011.pdf`
that was generated by `dvipdfm 0.13.2d`.

Workarounds:

- The example works with LuaTeX.
- It seems to work, if the PDF file is preprocessed by `pdfcrop`. Usually pdfTeX tries to detect the fonts in embedded PDF files and if the fonts are known, then pdfTeX uses the fonts directly ignoring the embedded fonts. Because of merging effects the file size can decrease. But the risk is that the embedded fonts and the fonts found by pdfTeX on its system might differ. `pdfcrop` disables all fonts, thus pdfTeX just copies the fonts from the included PDF file.

  ```
  pdfcrop analysiscompsSprJan2011.pdf
  ```

  generates `analysiscompsSprJan2011-crop.pdf` with removed white margins.
  The margins can also be kept. Then the `/MediaBox` inside the PDF file tells the dimension of the page:

  ```
  /MediaBox[0 0 612 792]
  ```

  that can be used as new bounding box for `pdfcrop`:

  ```
  pdfcrop -bbox "0 0 612 792" analysiscompsSprJan2011.pdf
  ```

  Finally `analysiscompsSprJan2011-crop.pdf` is used for embedding the file:

  ```
  \includepdf{analysiscompsSprJan2011-crop}
  ```

BTW, package `pdfpages` can also handle `.jpg` or `.png` files. Then the extension needs to be specified:

```
\includepdf{foobar.jpg}
```

However JPEG/PNG are bitmaps and JPEG is not a lossless compression, it is better to avoid them, if the original file is vector based like in this case.