# off-center PDF page in XeTeX using pdfpages package

Tags: xetex, pdf, embedding

I am trying to include a page of another pdf (in another folder) into a TeX file as it compiles. The other document has spaces in the title as well as in the path.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=6]{../AP Exams/2005 Form A/2005AFRQv2}
\end{document}
```

I end up with an off-center image of the page preceded by the path in the command on the left side. Does anyone know how to fix this? I'm using XeLaTeX for reasons not shown in this MWE.[image]

Comment: Does this solution help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114877/4736

Comment: Yes, switching to LuaLaTeX worked, thank you.

Comment: If you don't mind I will suggest to close this question as a duplicate.